# How to get Django admin.TabularInline to NOT require some items

Tags: python, django

```
class LineItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = LineItem
    extra = 10

class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Invoice
    inlines = (LineItemInline,)
```

and

```
class LineItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
    item_product_code = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    item_commodity_code = models.ForeignKey(CommodityCode)
    item_unit_cost = models.IntegerField()
    item_unit_of_measure = models.ForeignKey(UnitOfMeasure, default=0)
    item_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    item_total_cost = models.IntegerField()
    item_vat_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    item_vat_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

When I have it setup like this, the admin interface is requiring me to add data to all ten LineItems.  The LineItems have required fields, but I expected it to not require whole line items if there was no data entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's strange, it's supposed not to do that - it shouldn't require any data in a row if you haven't entered anything.

I wonder if the `default` options are causing it to get confused. Again, Django should cope with this, but try removing those and see what happens.

Also note that this:

```
item_unit_of_measure = models.ForeignKey(UnitOfMeasure, default=0)
```

is not valid, since 0 can not be the ID of a UnitOfMeasure object. If you want FKs to not be required, use `null=True, blank=True` in the field declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is default values.  The one pointed out above about UnitOfMeasure isn't the actual problem though, any field with a default= causes it to require the rest of the data to be present.  This to me seems like a bug since a default value should be subtracted out when determining if there is anything in the record that needs saving, but when I remove all the default values, it works.

In this code,
     item_unit_of_measure = models.ForeignKey(UnitOfMeasure, default=0)
it was a sneaky way of letting the 0th entry in the database be the default value.  That doesn't work unfortunately as he pointed out though.

Comment: Odd. Are you using an old version of Django? This very bug was fixed about a year ago (http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7975), and tests were included in the fix, so I'd be surprised if it regressed.